# Weird indent and imageView behaviour when selecting cells

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

In my tableview when selecting a cell, the ImageView on the left hand side of the cell indents and the imageView itself seems to change the content mode to aspect fit whereas I set it to aspect fill initially. (https://youtu.be/5Xl46kvtHIQ) Same thing sometimes happens when just scrolling through the tableview, so I guess there's some issue with redrawing the cells?

I don't really know what the issue could be, I just load the data into the Cell and that's pretty much it.

Here's my code for loading cells:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! HotelCell
cell.hotelNameLabel.text = hotels[indexPath.row].name
cell.vicinityLabel.text = hotels[indexPath.row].vicinity
cell.ratingView.value = CGFloat(hotels[indexPath.row].rating)

if let photo = photoDictionary[hotels[indexPath.row].id]{
    hotels[indexPath.row].firstImage = photo
}else{
    hotels[indexPath.row].firstImage = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "defaultImage")
}

cell.hotelImageView?.image = hotels[indexPath.row].firstImage
```

That's the HotelCell:

```
class HotelCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingView: HCSStarRatingView!
    @IBOutlet weak var hotelNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var vicinityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hotelImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

I hope someone can help me here, I'm kind of in a hurry. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your cell code?

Comment: What code exactly are you talking about? The tableview's delegate methods or something else?

Comment: no, your `HotelCell`

Comment: Alright, I added it but there's not much to see there